Check which VMSwitch is WSL2 effectively using
I have Windows 11 running Ubuntu 22 under WSL2.
In WSL2, a VMSwitch can be configured via .wslconfig on the Windows Host, or via /etc/wsl.conf inside the VM. This is used for bridging, and maybe for other reasons.
My question is how can I check through Powershell or some other scripting tool, which VMSwitch that VM is effectively using. So, I don't want to go try the networking inside the VM to see if it works, I want a 100% sure way of diagnosing how the VMSwitch connection is set between the host and WSL. Thanks!
